# Change email content on open

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-studio

Is their way or any AMPScript help to design content block which will change every time email open. For example if email is open b/w 6am to 11:59 am then Photo 1 will show else Photo 2?

Another example can be if email is open in AM then message start with "Good Morning" if email is open in PM then start with "Good Evening"

Answer (score 4):

You can use the new [Live Image](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_january_2018_content_builder.htm&type=5) feature of Content Builder. It is able to switch from one image to another, based on a trigger. This can a.o. be a date/time:[image: Trigger option: date and time]

It has a number of other options too:

[image]

To my knowledge, achieving same functionality in AmpScript is not possible, as it is parsed at sendtime - you need something that is updating on every email open.

If this content block is not available in your Content Builder, you need to reach out to your Salesforce Account Executive

If Live Image is not sufficient, you need to look into 3rd party solutions - such as e.g. [Movable Ink](http://movableink.com). The way emails are handled in email clients allows little room for dynamic adjustment of content on open. Basically you are only left with the option of replacing the content based on images - since you otherwise would need to utilise client side scripting. So not a limitation in SFMC but a general "nature" of the email itself.

Best regards - Lukas

Comment: Thank you Lukas. Image was just an example I was looking for more enhanced level of Personalization which trigger on Open. It could be based on Location for example if someone opening email in Texas then I want to show Texas restaurant if opening in NJ then NJ restaurants etc... 
But thanks again for reminding me on Live Image feature.

Comment: Again, it is not something you can do out-of-the-box on SFMC. Please see my updated reply above.

Comment: @Sohail - The only thing in emails that can be dynamic after send time are images as they are hosted outside of the email itself (except sometimes external style sheets - and CSS support isn't great enough to really utilize this in any groundbreaking way).  You can create a cloud page using ampscript to display different images and then reference that cloud page as an image, but that can get very expensive very quickly.  I would recommend the same as Lukas said - Live Image in SFMC, Movable Ink, LiveClicker, etc.

Comment: Yes - be aware of costs, as @Gortonington mentioned - Cloud Page views = Supermessages, so with multiple large sendouts, this can have an impact on your contract/license